# Get HTTP error RestClient::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized): Using 'rest-client' gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, rest-client

i have use the Ruby Gem `rest-client` for request on a url of a website. and i get the following error...

```
RestClient::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized):
  app/controllers/api/v1/channels_controller.rb:199:in `streaming_link'
```

help me to fix it. 
my controller method is bellow

```
def streaming_link
    url = URI.encode("http://eboundservices.com/hash/hash_app.php?code=orientplay")
    result = RestClient::Request.new({:user => "hashapp", :password => "PlayFair00",:method => :post, :url => url}).execute

    return render :json =>{:success=>true,:result=>result}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also struggling with rest-client and a 401 until I recognised, that it was because of the digest authentication the service needed. [Rest-Client currently did not support digest auth](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/102).

Instead I switched to [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), which supports it and with this it worked. Maybe it's the same with your 401.

```
@auth = {:username => 'hashapp', :password => 'PlayFair00'}
options = { :digest_auth => @auth }
response = HTTParty.get('http://eboundservices.com/hash/hash_app.php?code=orientplay', options)
```